# How thread works in web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webserver, puma, application-server

I am trying to understand how each web request works in rails application. To understand my logic I have written this dummy controller.

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts 'Going to Sleep'
    sleep 30.seconds

    render json: { message: 'ok' }
  end
end
```

I use puma as my application server. I ran rails server in production mode and visited  `locahost:3000/tests` in 5 different tabs in browser. My understanding was since puma is concurrent server, each request will run under different thread, that's why request blocked by first request won't block request for second request because that request will be handled by seperate thread.

But when I look into server log in terminal I see message `Going to Sleep` appear on first request and then ruby goes to sleep for 30 second. For second request and other requests I don't see message `Going to Sleep` in log file for 30 seconds (until first request have finished sleeping). This is confusing me a-lot, I thought for each 5 requests on different tabs on browser I will see message `Going to Sleep` immediately and non of request will block each other. But looks like I am wrong.

Can some one please explain it to me how it works ? My first request is blocking other request. Isn't that problem? In real world application if I make api call to 3rd party application and if it takes longer to get response back  than it will block request for other users ? Or do I need to make http request from different ip addresses for concurrency to work? Please explain.

**UPDATA**

Below is my puma configuration

```
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count
```

Comment: I have never tried such thing as studying sleep behavior. But because of GIL/GVL, only one thread can perform a Ruby task at one moment. Other threads can do I/O but not Ruby. If one thread is sleeping for 30 seconds, other threads can still do I/O. But basically no new thing can happen for 30 secs. An API call is I/O. Then 5 Ruby threads can perform an API call at the same time. So basically doing API calls is different than your test above.

Comment: What does your puma configuration look like? Especially in development environment, it is not uncommon to not have multiple threads configured.

Comment: `sleep` does not trigger the GIL in Ruby.

Comment: @spickermann I have updated my question with puma config. I have 5 thread set by default. Also I tried running both in dev and prod environment

Comment: @Casper does or doesn't. if `sleep` doesn't trigger GIL then multi thread should work ? and second request should not be blocked my first request ?

Comment: @r3b00t In basic Ruby threading, if you run `sleep` any other thread can then run. So yes running `sleep` in Rails should allow other threads to run. There must be some other configuration that is blocking Rails in this case. I don't know what is blocking, but it's not `sleep`.

Comment: Observation 1: If you call another controller, then it works. Accessing the same controller will block. I cannot find any documentation on this and why it works this way. But so far that is my finding.

Comment: @Casper even calling different method from same controller works fine as well. It will be good if I can understand why it's happening this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this condurum is that Rails is not blocking, but your browser is.

Browsers often reuse existing socket connections in order to reduce network traffic. In this case opening a new tab to exactly the same URL will try to reuse the existing socket connection to the server.

The browser is essentially trying to pipeline the request to the server through the already open connection. Since this socket connection is busy waiting for the `index` action of your `Tests` controller, the browser will block.

To see that Rails will indeed serve the same action from the same controller concurrently, you have to open new requests from another browser, or you can also test it from the command line with a tool like `wget`:

```
> wget -O - http://locahost:3000/tests &
> wget -O - http://locahost:3000/tests &
```

You will see both requests will go through fine, since they each make a new unique connection to the server.

**Conclusion**:

Rails is working fine. Concurrency and threading is working as expected. It's just that your browser is blocked because it's trying to reuse the already opened socket.

Comment: Thank you. Just tested this in different browser and it's working as expected. Once again thank you very much for making this clear and taking your time to experiment this for me.